# new line not inserted

Tags: java, file-io, file

This is the snippet:

```
String s1=new String("127.0.0.1 www.google.com127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");
String s2=new String("127.0.0.1 www.google.com" + "\n" + "127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");
byte buffer1[]=s1.getBytes();
byte buffer2[]=s2.getBytes();
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("f1.txt");
for(int i=0;i<buffer1.length;i++)
fos.write(buffer1[i]);
FileOutputStream fos2=new FileOutputStream("f2.txt");
for(int i=0;i<buffer2.length;i++)
fos2.write(buffer2[i]);
System.out.println("size of buffer1 = "+buffer1.length);
System.out.println("\nsize of buffer2 = "+buffer2.length);
String x=new String("s"+"\n"+"u");
System.out.println(x);
```

I do get 2 files named `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` in my current directory but I expect a `127.0.0.1 www.bing.com` to be in the new line in `f2.txt` but it occurs in the same line (i.e., the file is same as `f1.txt`).

Why don't I get a new line in `f2.txt` when I have inserted a new line character in String constructor?

Comment: What is your OS? what kind of line separator does it use? \r\l ?

Comment: @ Hubert win7.I use `\n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `\n` or similar things for new lines - this is platform dependent.

Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: @ Bozho `\n` works fine for `String x=new String("s"+"\n"+"u");
                     System.out.println(x);` then why not during file writing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what platform you're running on but, under Eclipse Galileo on Ubuntu, that works exactly as expected.

The code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
public class Find {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String s1=new String("127.0.0.1 www.google.com127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");
            String s2=new String("127.0.0.1 www.google.com" + "\n" +
                "127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");

            byte buffer1[]=s1.getBytes();
            byte buffer2[]=s2.getBytes();

            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("f1.txt");
            for(int i=0;i<buffer1.length;i++)
                fos.write(buffer1[i]);

            FileOutputStream fos2=new FileOutputStream("f2.txt");
            for(int i=0;i<buffer2.length;i++)
                fos2.write(buffer2[i]);

            System.out.println("size of buffer1 = "+buffer1.length);
            System.out.println("size of buffer2 = "+buffer2.length);

            String x=new String("s"+"\n"+"u");
            System.out.println(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
size of buffer1 = 46
size of buffer2 = 47
s
u
```

and the two files are different:

```
f1.txt:
    127.0.0.1 www.google.com127.0.0.1 www.bing.com
f2.txt:
    127.0.0.1 www.google.com
    127.0.0.1 www.bing.com
```

If you're using an operating system that doesn't use `\n` as the line separator (such as Windows), you'll still get the same output but the tools that you use to *look* at that file (or process it) may not work as expected. If you replaced `\n` with `\r\n`, you'd probably find the other tools then worked fine for Windows.

But, for portability, use the `line.separator` property rather than `\n` (or `\r\n`) directly:

```
String s2=new String("127.0.0.1 www.google.com" +
    System.getProperty("line.separator") +
    "127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");
```

Comment: same here on windows 7 with eclipse helios

Comment: The point is, as @Bozho says, that solution is platform dependant - so it will work for _some_ of you.

Comment: @ paxdiablo every thing is the same except the last output of f1.txt and f2.txt

Answer (score 2):

Try to find out what the separator should be. You can try `\r\n` for instance. It differs between Linux and Windows what characters are used for a "new line" (linefeed and carriage return)

*(A carriage return means that the cursor goes to the first character, a linefeed means that the cursor goes "one line down". Depending on what your OS does, you need one or both)*

Comment: `/n` has been working fine on my OS.How is it that /n is not working during file writing,when the output length it shows is 46,47 respectively

Comment: yeah , `\r\n` worked for me, but not any one individual , 
@Nanne how is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Printstream over fileoutputstream:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("f2.txt");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(f);
ps.print("127.0.0.1 www.google.com");
ps.println(); //this writes your new line
ps.print("127.0.0.1 www.bing.com");
ps.close();
```

ref: 
[How do I write a newline using FileOutputStream](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080512164136AAL2rHq)